# Incorrect syntax near the keyword when using EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Why am getting this error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword

when I execute the below code

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE  EXISTS ( (SELECT 1
                 FROM   [dbo].[item_table] i
                 WHERE  i.priority_id = p.priority_id)
         AND filter = @filter )
        OR ( @filter IS NULL )
```

For past two hours am cracking my head couldn't get anything. I want to ignore the `Where` clause when `@filter` variable is `NULL`

Comment: where is your column filter? is it in [dbo].[priority_table] or is it in [dbo].[item_table]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `Open parenthesis` before `EXISTS`

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE  ( EXISTS (SELECT 1
                 FROM   [dbo].[item_table] i
                 WHERE  i.priority_id = p.priority_id)
         AND filter = @filter )
        OR ( @filter IS NULL )
```

Comment: Looks like sqlalchemy orm doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

if filter column in  [dbo].[item_table]

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE EXISTS
            (SELECT 1
             FROM [dbo].[item_table] i
             WHERE (i.priority_id = p.priority_id
                   AND @filter = filter)
                  OR @filter IS NULL);
```

if the filter is in [dbo].[priority_table]

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE(EXISTS
            (SELECT 1
             FROM [dbo].[item_table] i
             WHERE i.priority_id = p.priority_id)
      AND @filter = filter)
     OR @filter IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not valid

```
EXISTS ( ( SELECT 1
             FROM   [dbo].[item_table] i
            WHERE  i.priority_id = p.priority_id 
         )
         AND filter = @filter 
       )
```

SELECT 1 is not equivalent to AND filter

Answer (score 0):

This is not ju-ju magic. Exists in a where clause is just written like a sub-query (specifically a semi-join), thus (extra lines added for emphasis):

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE  EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   [dbo].[item_table] i
    WHERE  i.priority_id = p.priority_id
    AND (i.filter = @filter 
    OR  @filter IS NULL)
)
```

The critical bit is to make sure you use table aliaes, so you refer correctly to the outer and inner tables of the sub-query.

Comment: In fact, you can do a bit of magic here. If you replace the SELECT 1 with SELECT (1/0) - it still works just fine. For an EXISTS / NOT EXISTS semi-join everything between the SELECT and FROM on the sub-query is completely ignored (even a divide by zero).

Answer (score 0):

Or the clearer alternative to the MotoGP answer is (which makes no assumptions about  @filter = 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM   [dbo].[priority_table] p
WHERE  EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   [dbo].[item_table] i
    WHERE  i.priority_id = p.priority_id
    AND i.filter = @filter
)
OR ( @filter IS NULL )
```